# Rewrite hostname on OS X

Tags: networking, macos, dns, hosts-file

I'm trying to rewrite a hostname using the hosts-file in OS X using the hosts-file and the following entry `localhost        db` meaning that when i access http://db/ it should in reality access http://localhost/

[image]

It seems like it only accepts ip-addresses because `db` does not resolve to `localhost` even though the DNS-cache have been flushed several times.

Is it impossible to resolve a hostname from another hostname, or is there another place to configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the entry `localhost        db` to `127.0.0.1        db`. I don't think that it is possible to resolve a hostname from another hostname.

Comment: Instead of adding a line, you may also just tag `db` onto the end of one (or both) of the `localhost` lines, i.e. "`127.0.0.1 localhost db`".